# Extension of Sobolev functions

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Actually I am searching if $u$ belong to $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ then why extension out side by zero does not belong to $W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in general? Can some body help?

Comment: Because of the "jump" on $\partial \Omega$. That destroys (weak) differentiability.

Comment: Example: $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $u(x)=1$ for all $x\in \Omega$. If you extend it to be $0$ outside of $\Omega$ then its first distributional derivative will have two $\delta$s at $0$ and at $1$, and so it won't be a function.

Answer (score 4):

We can resume the two comment given by @DanielFischer and @GiuseppeNegro with the following result (see [Leoni](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=W3RLWwnY0RkC&pg=PA279&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) page 293):

If $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $p\in [1,\infty)$, then for almost every segment in $\Omega$ parallel to the coordinate axes, $u$ restricted to this segment is absolutely continuous. In fact, this result is part of a classification os Sobolev spaces and I suggest you to take a look in the book of Leoni that I have cited.

Also, it is worth to note that when the dimension is $1$, because of the last result, every Sobolev function has a continuous representative.

Comment: Or at least has a continuous representative.

Comment: Yes @UmbertoP., you are right, let me fix it.

Comment: Sorry, but where is this answer?

Comment: I think the counter example given by Giuseppe Negro is sufficient to establish a contradiction. Thank you